# how to escape special character in password for powershell command from salt

Tags: linux, bash, powershell, salt-stack

I am trying to execute a PowerShell command on a Windows minion from salt master on Linux, but my password parameter contains special characters.
I have used single quotes but no luck.
When I am using escape character it is being included in password string and access is getting denied.

I am trying to run the following:

```
salt win143minion cmd.run "powershell Deploy-Package -Username salttest -Password S@lt!@#test -Target xx.xx.xx.xx -MofPath C:\nkv\dsc\moffiles"
```

On executing this i am getting this:

> bash: !@#test: event not found

Comment: try using single quotes instead of double quotes

Comment: @Aserre He already tried that, as stated in the question.

Comment: I have tried  putting parameter password in single quotes. Do you want me to put the whole command in single quotes?

Comment: There are bash options to turn off the processing of history expansion (i.e. the `!` chars), but you'll have to look them up.Good luck.